# How to convert date to UTC using moment.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to convert Date Object to this 'yyyy-mm-ddT00:00:00.000Z' format. but I can't seem to find a way to get moment.js to return a format. Here is what I am doing:

```
var test = new Date();
var formattedDate = moment(test).format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fffffff'Z'");
```

Comment: `var formattedDate = new Date().toISOString();`

Answer (score 2):

You got it almost right try the following

```
 var test = new Date();
 var formattedDate = moment(test).toISOString()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the format and UTC method of `momentjs`

```
moment(YOUR DATE).utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
moment.utc(test).format();
```